# I want to remove one script tag from page in vuejs and laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-mix

I am adding a special script file for more functionality in that component but when I change component I want to remove the script tag.

the following method is used to add script tags in the vue component.

```
created() {
    this.dynamicallyLoadScript("/assets/libs/moment/moment.min.js");s
},
methods: {
    dynamicallyLoadScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

now when I change component I want to remove that script.
help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `beforeDestroy` lifecycle method and remove the script from your document.

To do that, you need to save the DOM element created from you `appendChild` in your Vue component and remove the script tag in `beforeDestroy` lifecycle.

```
methods: {
    dynamicallyLoadScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;

        this.scriptEle = document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}

beforeDestroy() {
  document.body.removeChild(this.scriptEle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id for that script tag, and later in the destroyed() method you can get that script calling it by id and delete it.